# How to generate Sails.js models and controllers from Swagger OpenAPI spec?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Following the *design-first* approach, I want to generate my Sails.js 1.0 models, controllers, and routes from an existing OpenAPI spec. I have found modules that work in the other direction and can generate the spec from the Sails.js config. But that does not help me. Any advice?

Comment: There is https://openapi-generator.tech/ that has generators for many languages and stacks, but not for Sails.js, unfortunately.